# OpenStreetMaps: How do I get the number of PoI's for a given country?

Tags: openstreetmap

I am curious to derive the number of a given type of Points of Interest (POIs) for a given country - in my case, specifically India and Indonesia.

My understanding is that `osmfilter` is the program for this, but I am mildly surprised at how low the numbers are.

For instance:

```
$ ./osmfilter india.o5m --out-count=tourism | grep hotel
   2698     hotel

$ ./osmfilter india.o5m --out-count | grep cuisine
   2172     cuisine
      1     disused:cuisine

$ ./osmfilter india.o5m --out-count=amenity | grep atm
   1978     atm
      2     bank;atm
      1     atm;pharmacy
```

Less than 2500 hotels, restaurants, and atms each seems like an incredibly low number for a country such as India - or is it just that the OSM dataset is still very sparse?

Many thanks!
/YGA

Comment: Note that for restaurants you have to check the [amenity=restaurant](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:amenity%3Drestaurant) key. And for ATMs there is also the [atm=yes](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:atm%3Dyes) tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numbers appear to be right. The Overpass API returns about the same number of Hotels in India: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/57h (same for [restaurants](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/57j) and [ATMs](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/57i)). Your approach of calculating counts seems to be fine.

Generally speaking, the percentage of already mapped POIs of a certain category per country can vary a lot. But even in “well mapped” European countries one can find coverage rates in the rage of 20% for POIs like hotels (example: Austria - 4k in [OSM](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/57k) vs. 20k according to [Statistics Austria](http://www.statistik.at/web_en/statistics/tourism/accommodation/accommodation_capacity/index.html)).

Comment: Absolutely fantastic answer - thank you!

A set of followup questions if you have the time: Do you know how OSM itself tracks its own coverage levels?  
* Is there any comprehensive report where it self-examines?
* Do you know any cross-comparisons between OSM and other sources, e.g. Google or Bing Maps, either in developed countries or in developing countries?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no regular global self-examination in OSM with regards of coverage levels. From time to time people do perform analyses of certain aspects, for example single countries (like this [report](http://www.fossgis.de/konferenz/2013/programm/attachments/431_datenqualitaet_osm_schweiz.pdf) about Switzerland) or specific datums (e.g. [addresses](http://www.openstreetmap.org/user/SimonPoole/diary/19626)).

OSM certainly has been compared to commercial map providers in the past, but I'm not aware of any recent and scientifically profound study, I'm afraid.